# Multiprocessing two functions using and modifying the same list

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have 4 lists of 3 floats each. I have two functions (implemented as one function actually - a different int argument changes the element of the lists it acts on) that I want to run in parallel. They both take all of the lists and use them to do some calculations with them. The results of the first function - 4 floats - one for each list - are meant to change the second element of every list, while the results of the second function are meant to change the third element in all the lsits. Then I want to move on the next iteration, where the functions do the same but with the updated lists (the first element in all of them stays constant).

Simple code to represent my idea

```
l1 = [a,b,c]
l2 = [d,e,f]
l3 = [g,h,i]
l4 = [j,k,l]
def func(l1, l2, l3, l4, k):
    do something with the lists on element k of them
    return (x1, x2, x3, x4, k)

pool = multi.Pool(processes = 2)
while nstep <= maxnsteps:
    for i in range(1,3):
        pool.apply_async(func, args = (xval, yval, vxval, vyval, i,))
    nstep = nstep + 1
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

So, for the next value of nstep, I want the functions to use updated versions of the lists with the values that they computed in the previous iteration. I have the feeling that I am going completely wrongly about that

Comment: Does `func` take a significant amount of time to complete? If not, using multiprocessing this way may be slower than serial code.

Comment: Not much, I did it in a serial way in the beginning, but maxnsteps is a very big number so I need a way of speeding up the process - therefore I went for multiprocessing - I am not even sure that this is the best way to use the module here

Comment: That the two (short) calls to `func` must complete before moving on to the next iteration makes the problem unamicable to concurrent processing.

Comment: So what is your question here? If you want to know if your code is fast enough just try your approach. But first ask yourself if a two times speed up is what you want (more likely it is less than that). Otherwise try to optimize the function using a performance profiler and/or use pypy instead of the python interpreter.

Comment: I want to know whether the following is possible: You have a list with values. A few functions take these values and simultaneously do some calculations with them and then each function changes a different value of the list. And this is I want to be a single iteration of a loop - on the next step of the loop they do the same, but with the updated list with values. The problematic thing is that each function needs all the values of the list to do the computation, but then changes only 1 element of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code without multiprocessing. You need to copy the lists before processing them with `l1_copy1=list(l1)`. Then you can merge the modified lists from the two functions like `new_l1=[l1_copy1[0], l1_copy2[1], l1[2]]` etc. 
Another remark; use a matrice or create a class matrice to hold the lists, so you can iterate over them.

```py
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [4,5,6]
l3 = [7,8,9]
l4 = [10,11,12]

def increment_at_position_k(l1, l2, l3, l4, k):
    l1, l2, l3, l4 = list(l1), list(l2), list(l3), list(l4) # copy lists (otherwise the list is modified directly)
    l1[k] += 1
    l2[k] += 1
    l3[k] += 1
    l4[k] += 1
    return (l1, l2, l3, l4, k)

for iterations in [0]:
    results = []
    for i in [1,2]:
        ret = increment_at_position_k(l1, l2, l3, l4, i)
        results.append(ret)
    for res in results:
        local_l1, local_l2, local_l3, local_l4, k = res # unpack result
        #update global list
        l1[k] = local_l1[k]
        l2[k] = local_l2[k]
        l3[k] = local_l3[k]
        l4[k] = local_l4[k]
print l1
print l2
print l3
print l4
```